# how to show image from absolute path in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i'm new with angularjs during get image path from database as absolute Path
as (c:\userimages\user.jpg)
i found that angularjs show images that have relative path ,so my question is
how to convert absolute path to relative path and use ng-src to show the image.
thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with angular. If you open html file, it will read absolute path and show image. But when you host website, it can't find that url any more, because server gives access to only specified public folder where are all the images and assets.

Comment: With nodejs you can get relative path like this: `path.relative(from, to);`. [See docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to)

Comment: use `<img src="subfolder/your_image_path.extension" />` this may help you

Comment: thanks for your answer , if subfolder located in my web application OK,But if subfolder located in c: or d: (c:\subfolder) no image appear

Comment: The image saved in C:\Img folder not in my web folder , this is my AngularJS function that working fine if i saved the images in my web folder but does show the images if the images saved in C:\Img folder $scope.getuserimg = function (ContactUserId) {
           
                $http.get("/Document/GetUserImage?id=" + ContactUserId).success(function (data) {
                
                    $scope.imgUrl = $scope.UserImgPath + data;
                    alert($scope.imgUrl);
                })
         
        }